# What to do with an accepted answer that doesn't really answer the question?

Tags: discussion

In [How do I install Chromium on Linux Mint using Software Manager?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5196/), the OP (Jonas) seems to have given up trying to find an answer for his question and accepted an answer that doesn't quite work.  Then JoseF comes along and posts (as an answer) that he is having a similar problem.

I flagged JoseF's post for moderator attention since it's not an answer, but on second thought I'm not sure what to do from his perspective.  He can't offer a bounty with his 1 reputation.  Repost as a new question?  In which case what do we do with the old question?

Comment: Is the problem solved, already? I don't see JoseF at all in that discussion. But the answer of NES seems accepted, while the comment says, it didn't work. But one of the comments NES gave seemed to work. A little bit wired. :)

Comment: @user JoseF's answer was converted to a comment on the question

Comment: The moderator (Michael Mrozek) converted the post to a comment, which ended up below the break.  I just now voted up the comment, so it should be visible now.  See also the pre-migration version of this question for Michael's thoughts.

Comment: would starting another question with reference to the old one be considered bad form? The old answer does not work for the new person (logically, as it was not a real answer), and to encourage actual new answers you don't want to continue on an already answered question?

Comment: @Nanne: I like that from the perspective of getting a question answered; it feels better than just re-asking the question with no reference.  From a searcher's perspective, though, having the two questions adds extra chaff to wade through.  Maybe the question scores will help take care of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have 100 for connecting with other SE account(s) they can start a bounty already. Basically that's what I would do if I come to a new SE site and very badly want an answer.

There is nothing much a new user with reputation of 1 can do, not even comment or vote up. I would recommend some social effort, such as opening a meta question, or asking on the chat page. If he is lucky enough somebody else may open a bounty on the question and ask for another answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be an unpopular post, but if I were him I would write a new question, even if it's a duplicate.

The fact that it's more likely to get a better answer can't be disputed. Then the old question can be closed as a duplicate of the new one.

Comment: The new question is likely to get closed as a dupe of the old one before any new answers get posted.

Comment: Do the moderators who mark questions as duplicates ensure that they understand the subject of the question before doing so? I'm wondering about dupes of questions with accepted-answers that might help the OP but don't answer the actual question (eg. because the answer is now out of date or the question was badly worded or misleading and the OP actually meant something else).

Answer (score 0):

To accept or not to accept, that is the question.

But it is up to the OP to accept or not to accept.

So if an answer is accepted by the OP, its probably good enough for him or her.

Comment: All true, but this doesn't address the question at all. He asked what a second person who has the same problem which *isn't* solved by the accepted answer should do

Comment: not necessarily, it could just be because some one left him a rant about "you'll get better answers if you improve your accept rate" :)